# How to limit topics returned by a command to most recent 10 instead of all topics ever written?

Tags: javascript, node.js, limit

I have a system where users can type in a command and get a return of all topics, sorted by date and time. The topics are growing and it takes a while for all of them to load, how can I limit it so that the user only gets 10 most recent topics instead of all of them?

```
function finishQuery() {
    query
        .populate('creator editedBy')
        .sort('lastCommentDate')
        .exec(function (err, topics) {
            if (err) return shell.error(err);
            if (!isGui) {
                if (topics.length === 0)
                    shell.warn('No results.');
                else {
                    topics.forEach(function (topic) {
                        var currentUser = shell.getVar('currentUser'),
                            topicView;
                        for (var index = 0; index < topic.views.length; index++) {
                            var view = topic.views[index];
                            if (view.userId == currentUser._id) {
                                topicView = view;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        var newCommentCount = topicView ? topic.commentCount - topicView.commentCount : topic.commentCount;
                        shell.log('{{0}} {1}'.format(topic.id, topic.title), {
                            bold: true,
                            dontType: true,
                            cssClass: newCommentCount === 0 && topicView ? 'dim' : ''
                        });
                        shell.log(
                            '{0} by {1}'.format(topic.dateFromNow(), topic.creator.username),
                            { cssClass: 'sub', dontType: true }
                        );
                        shell.log(topic.tags.join(','), { cssClass: 'sub', dontType: true });
                        if (topic.commentCount > 0) {
                            shell.log(
                                '{0} {1} ({2} new)'.format(
                                    topic.commentCount,
                                    topic.commentCount === 1 ? 'Comment' : 'Comments',
                                    newCommentCount
                                ),
                                { cssClass: 'sub', dontType: true }
                            );
                        }
                        shell.log();
                    });
                }
            }
            else {}

        });
}
```

Comment: Please narrow the scope of the question. Pasting in a glob of code doesn't help others help you. If you wanted a code review try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're querying is most likely using SQL on the server to grab all of the topics. Just find it and add `LIMIT 0, 10` to the appropriate query.

P.S. this will return the first 10 in the database, so make sure it's sorting them first.

Comment: query = query.limit (10); before finishQuery(); did it, thanks